# Isometries of an infinite ribbon

Tags: group-theory, isometry

Consider the group of isometries $N'$ of an infinite ribbon
$$R=\left\{(x,y)| -1 \le y \le 1\right\}.$$
The following elements are in $N'$:
$$t_a:(x,y)\to(x+a,y)$$
$$s:(x,y)\to(-x,y)$$
$$r:(x,y)\to(x,-y)$$
$$\rho:(x,y)\to(-x,-y)$$
I have shown that they satisfy the following relations:
$$t_at_b=t_{a+b}$$
$$s^2=r^2=\rho^2=1$$
$$st_a=t_{-a}s$$
$$rt_a=t_ar$$
$$\rho t_a=t_{-a}\rho$$
$$rs=sr=\rho$$
$$s\rho=\rho s=r$$
$$r\rho=\rho r=s$$
Then I am asked to consider the frieze pattern, which is a pattern on the ribbon that is periodic and whose group of symmetries is discrete.

Does it mean I only need to restrict the $a$ to integer multiples of the period of the pattern, and all is done?

Comment: Does it mean putting a square lattice on the ribbon?

Comment: From wiki, it seems to mean like a wallpaper pattern but in 1D. So does it mean I just need to restrict the $a$ to integer multiples of a certain $d$ and all is done?

Comment: Well I mean if you cut the ribbon up into squares, and made sure it coincided with the origin in the right way, it would have a discrete group of symmetries. Looking at examples they just seem to be general [shapes](http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/frieze/friezepat.html), and a square is a nice shape

Comment: If you have a frieze pattern on your ribbon, the group of isometries you obtain is dependent on the pattern, since different patterns give you different symmetries (and thus a different group). Are you given an illustration, perhaps?

Comment: No, it just defined frieze pattern as in my post, and then asked me to write down all the symmetries:"Classify the corresponding symmetry groups, identifying those that differ in the choice of origin and unit length on the ribbon. Begin by making some patterns with different symmetries. Make a careful case analysis when proving your results."